# collection_select with one-to-many / many-to-many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I use `collection_select` in a One-ToMany-ToOne scenario. Here is what I have

The application manages projects. Each project has a different set of languages that it supports. People can now post messages in the projects
in one of the languages that the project supports.

Simplified class structure:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :languageprojects
  has_many :languages, through: :languageprojects
end

class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :languageprojects
  has_many :projects, through: :languageprojects
  def to_s
    language
  end
end

class Languageproject < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :project
end

class Projectmessage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :language
  belongs_to :project
end
```

How to I format the collection_select in the form where the users enters a new message (Projectmessage). The user must be able to select one of the languages that the project supports.

I want to display the languages name in the native language of the user thus the languages are stored in the table LANGUAGES in the format

```
en
fr
ru
```

Then I keep the translations of these languages in the locales folder under en.yml, fr.yml, ru.yml. E.g.:

```
en:
  language_en: English
  language_fr: French
  language_ru: Russian
```

I got so far:

```
<%= form.collection_select :language_id, Languageproject.all, :id, :language, { include_blank: false }, { class: 'form-control' } %>
```

This shows the values of the table entries (i.e. en, fr, ru). How do I incorporate the language translation? I want the dropdown to show English, French, Russian

Obviously I can always code it instead of using 'collection_select' but am hoping for a 'Ruby' way of solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `options_for_select`

```
<%= f.select :language_id, options_for_select(@language_project.languages.all.map{|l| [l.language, l.id]}, @language.id), include_blank: false, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Comment: Thanks for guiding me the right direction, almost there, just need to add the I18n translation, got it all working with:

`<%= form.select :language_id, options_for_select(projectmessage.project.languageprojects.all.map{|l| [I18n.t("language_#{l.language}"), l.id]} ), include_blank: false, class: 'form-control' %>`

Comment: Can't upvote quite yet, need some more reputation to do so.

Comment: I just upvoted ur question so hopefully you’ll be on your way to accessing those privileges soon!

Comment: My bad, almost correct, this is the final version I have used: `<%= form.select :language_id, options_for_select(projectmessage.project.languageprojects.all.map{|l| [I18n.t("language_#{l.language}"), l.id]} ), {include_blank: false}, {class: 'form-control'} %>`